# Why does this binary search implementation make the browser unresponsive?

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary-search

I've tried binary search in my chrome console. But when I've ran the code, the whole chrome got hanged and I had to kill the pages:

```
var arr = [1, 3, 5, 8];
var binary = function (arr, search) {

    var low = 0;
    var high = arr.length - 1;
    var mid = (high + low) / 2;
    while (low <= high) {

        if (search === arr[mid]) {

            return mid;
        } else if (search > arr[mid]) {
            low = mid + 1;

        } else {
            high = mid - 1;
        }

    }
    return -1;
};

console.log(binary(arr, 3));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `mid` is *always* 1.5, because it's calculated before the loop.

Instead, move the `mid` calculation *within* the loop, and calculate it as the rounded average of `high` and `low`:

```js
var arr = [1, 3, 5, 8];
var binary = function(arr, search) {

  var low = 0;
  var high = arr.length - 1;
  var mid;

  while (low <= high) {
    mid = Math.round((high + low) / 2);
    if (search === arr[mid]) {
      return mid;
    } else if (search > arr[mid]) {
      low = mid + 1;
    } else {
      high = mid - 1;
    }
  }
  return -1;
};

console.log(binary(arr, 3)); //1
console.log(binary(arr, 8)); //3
console.log(binary(arr, 17)); //-1
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in this line

```
var mid = (high + low) / 2;
```

Since `mid` is a floating point value, `arr[mid]` always returns `undefined`. You can confirm this, like this

```
var arr = [1, 3, 5, 8];
console.log(arr[1.5]);
// undefined
```

**Solution**

1. To fix this, you can convert that to an integer, like this

   ```
   var mid = parseInt((high + low) / 2, 10);
   ```
2. As pointed out by Rick in the comments, the `mid` calculation has to happen within the `while` loop. So, the `while` loop would look like this

   ```
   while (low <= high) {
       mid = parseInt((high + low) / 2, 10);
       if (search === arr[mid]) {
           return mid;
       } else if (search > arr[mid]) {
           low = mid + 1;
       } else {
           high = mid - 1;
       }
   }
   ```